# How do I set a Stack Overflow bookmark to show the latest questions for any of my "interesting" bookmarks?

Tags: support, tag-watching

I found a Stack Overflow generated URL that seemed to give me a list of the latest questions for all of my "Interesting Tag" links:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=asp.net-mvc-2%2basp.net-mvc%2bvisual-studio-2010&sort=newest&pagesize=15
```

I added this to my browser toolbar so I could quickly "catch up" on new questions of interest to me, but the page from the above URL has not updated for 3 days :(

Reason: This URL seems to "AND" all the links together.

Is there an equivalent URL syntax for "OR"ing  my "Interesting Tags"?

I have searched the Stack Overflow web for clues or hints, but perhaps I am missing something SO OBVIOUS it is eluding me. If so I am sorry for any waste of time and bandwidth, but if someone can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful!

Comment: Belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=asp.net-mvc-2%20or%20asp.net-mvc%20or%20visual-studio-2010&sort=newest&pagesize=15
```

It [seems to work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=asp.net-mvc-2%20or%20asp.net-mvc%20or%20visual-studio-2010&sort=newest&pagesize=15).

Comment: thank you Walter ... that seems to work fine ! :)